# iPod nano 6th generation jailbreak

Tags: jailbreak, ipod-nano

I have an iPod nano 6th generation that I don't use at all. This is because although being a music player, I usually just use my iPhone for that same purpose. So I was wondering whether it is possible to modify the software so that I could use it for another purpose such as a dedicated watch, a memory stick with a display, a miniature game system, a leveler or something else along the lines.

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is that there are some things you can do with it, but it's not easy and there aren't specific tools built for it, and there's no Cydia, etc.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Then how was Apple able to even create an OS on it?

Comment: Apple was able to put an OS on it because Apple designed it that way, and only Apple has the keys to develop new software for its devices. Jailbreaking, in a basic sense, is achieved by bypassing the key checking on a device, thus allowing it to run code written by anybody. Basically, nobody has bothered to figure out how to bypass that key checking on the iPod Nano yet, and at this point, it's safe to say that nobody ever will (especially with the Apple Watch available).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Well I guess I can't find how one may crack the key, unless you force the device to go through a USB information logger while restoring.

Comment: The keys aren't crackable by design, because the relevant key isn't actually stored on the device - only Apple has access to the key in their special key signing room at Apple headquarters. The software keys used on Apple devices are built on [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). Apple also has some more information (that can confirm my statements) in their [iOS security white paper](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Wait so if I restore my iPod nano normally through iTunes by using a cable that also logs the data that is going through it, I won't be able to find the encrypted public key that will specifically unlock my iPod?

Comment: You can read the public key off the device just fine, it's the private key that matters, and that's the one that isn't located on the device - it's located at Apple's headquarters. Only the private key can sign software for the device. If the software wasn't signed by the private key, the device will refuse to run it (the device verifies it using the public key). The only way around it is to bypass the signature verification, and nobody has bothered to do this for the iPod Nano.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson so is bypassing the signature verification basically tricking the device that it has been properly signed?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I think I get it now. So Apple gets the OS where they check it if it is legit. Then they use their encrypt key to encrypt the file. This goes into the device where the device uses its decrypt key to unlock the OS. Thus the only way to go into the device is by having an encrypt key, which apply won't allow the encryption if it is not apple's software. And if we encrypt a different OS with a different key, the iPod cannot unlock it and won't proceed. So yes this is hard to jailbreak. How may one trick the iPod nano that the key is right?

Comment: Yes, that is all correct from a basic standpoint. I don't know of anybody that has bypassed the key verification. It is very complicated and is usually only done by expert computer security researchers as it requires vast amounts of knowledge and experience to accomplish such a task.